# Problemas con Composer al crear proyecto de laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

Hola Amigos intento realizar un proyecto en laravel desde composer pero me da un error que la verdad antes nunca me paso pero ahora no se que ocurre. Gracias por la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bueno en si el problema fue el firewall del antivirus que tenia, al quitarlo me dejó descargar todo lo que tenía

Comment: y no crees que es una solución poco practica, desactivar tu herramienta de protección? por que mejor no creaste una regla de excepción para dejar pasar a composer

Comment: Sinceramente a mi me funciono y no mlvi nada más q eso

Comment: esta no es una solucion, estas vulnerando tu sistema